# change event in form_dropdown codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dropdown

I developed 2 drop downs using `form_dropdown` I want to change 2nd dropdown to the change event in 1st one. can i do it using js ?

```
public function get_employee_to_division($seleted_val = '') {
        $this->db->select(array('emp_profile.emp_id', 'emp_profile.emp_no', 'emp_profile.name_short'));
        $this->db->from('emp_in_division');
        $this->db->join('`emp_profile`', '`emp_in_division`.`emp_id` = `emp_profile`.`emp_id`', 'INNER');
        $this->db->where('emp_in_division.division_id' . '=' . '1');
        $this->db->order_by("emp_profile.emp_no", "asc");
        $d = $this->db->get();

        if ($d) {
            $data = array();
            $data[] = "Select Employee";
            foreach ($d->result() as $row) {

// Add array keys to the array while looping...
                $data[$row->emp_id] = $row->emp_no . '-' . $row->name_short;
            }

            $emp_dropdown = form_dropdown('employer_id" id="employer_id" class="form-control text-left"', $data, $seleted_val);
            return $emp_dropdown;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

here is my drop downs
[image: dropdowns]

Comment: Hi sure u can do it. Get an event from the first dropdown (onchange) and update second dropdown (update the value of the select tag).

Comment: yes you can do it